# Unable to summarize the complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I implemented a graph algorithm and I found out that the time complexity of the algorithm is `O(V) + O(log V) + O(E) * O(log V)`. The best I could come up as the complexity of the algorithm is `O((V + E) log V)`. It doesn't look right. What exactly would be the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: Assuming that `E` is at least `O(V)`, then the complexity is simply `O(E logV)` since that's the term that's going to grow fastest. `O(E logV) >> O(V) >> O(logV)` for large `E` and `V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your algorithm is `O(V) + O(E) * O(log V)` (logV is a minor term).

Now if you have a sparse graph (graph where number of edges is approximately the number of vertices), your complexity is `O(V * log V)`.

When you have a dense graph (graph where number of edges is close to `V * (V - 1) / 2`), your complexity is `O(V^2 * log V)`